# One function to rule multiple buttons, and then some

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 7 buttons. They are distributed on top of a background image and interacting with it. They are placed absolutely. I have created a jQuery function to animate one of the buttons height. The button expands upwards. Check it out here: http://hdpano.no/bf/newindex.html and click the top left button named Deck 8.

I wish this function to handle all the buttons, but there are some variables. The baseline of each button varies, and i need to subtract from it as i expand the height. I also wish to close any other open button if one clicks another.

Here is the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('#link8').toggle(
function()
{
  $('#deck8').animate({height: "25px",top:"202"}, 500);
},
function()
{
$('#deck8').animate({height: "150",top:"76"}, 500);

});

});
```

The function is quite basic and I have stripped it of all my attempts to make it work with the other buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you're looking for.  Replace the code in your page with this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('.link').click(function() {
            var $me = $(this);
            if ($me.height() == 150) {
                $me.animate({height: "25px",top:"+=126"}, 500);
            } else {
                $(".link").each(function() {
                    if ($(this) != $me) {
                        if ($(this).height() == 150) {
                            $(this).animate({height: "25px",top:"+=126"}, 500);
                        }
                    } 
                });
                $me.animate({height: "150px",top:"-=126"}, 500);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can toggle the position with += and -= so it uses relative positioning, rather than absolute positioning, so that code affects all the divs on the page with class "link".

Comment: I just made a change after rereading your question.  It now closes open buttons when you open a new one.

Comment: I used this code. Thank you so very much. I tried to add some background animation as well.

    $(this).animate({"backgroundColor": "rgba(203, 54, 191, .4)"},500)

But it doesn't work. Any tips on that? Or should I open a new thread?

Comment: You should open a new thread for that.  I know that IE8 and below doesn't like rgba, but other than that it should work.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in the toggle functions would be the element that is clicked.

Here is what I would do:

- remove the `<br/>` tags. Use margin/padding to achieve spacing.
- basically you want to expand/collapse the element ".link" (the container) for the height of the contained `<ul>`.
- use "+=" or "-=" with the animate function to automatically add/remove the specified value.
- as your buttons start *collapsed*, you should invert the two functions in the toggle

Here a code that is more general:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // on click of any link with class ".linkContent"
    $('.linkContent').toggle(
    function() {
            // get the parent ".link" container
        var $parent = $(this).parent(),
            // get the full height of the <ul> to show/hide + the height of the link
            h = $parent.find('ul').outerHeight() + $(this).outerHeight();

        // animate using += and -= to avoid setting explicit values
        $parent.animate({ height: '+=' + h, top: '-=' + h }, 500);
    },
    function() {
        var $parent = $(this).parent(),
            h = $parent.find('ul').outerHeight() + $(this).outerHeight();
        $parent.animate({ height: '-=' + h, top: '+=' + h }, 500);
    });

});
```

The following demo shows the code in action. You might have to tweak it a bit to get the exact height to add/remove but you get the idea:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/gs9DN/)**

Comment: Thank you so very much. I tried .parent, but never got it to work the way i wanted. This looks great and I'll try and implement it straight away. Then I'll earn some reputation and upvote your answer. :D

Comment: I have changed the code a bit: inverted the two toggle functions (as the buttons starts collapsed) and the computation of the `h`. Check the updated fiddle.

Comment: You've done what I originally did and missed the bit about closing any open buttons when you open a new one.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add a class eg `.deck` to each button, then toggle `.deck'. Inside the toggle function use`$(this)` to refer to the current button.